# Foundation (ZURB) Tooltips Flickering

Tags: zurb-foundation, tooltip

I am using the built in Tooltips in Foundation (version 4.3.1) by Zurb.

They work but if you do not keep the mouse still the tooltip will flicker. Is it possible to stop the flickering from happening?

I assume this is happening because the tool tips are over text and the mouse technically goes off the text and comes back onto the text quickly so it flickers. How do I prevent this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to solve my problem and this may help others.

The issue was the cursor not staying on the text thus causing the flickering.

I added a background the same color as my background with a little padding and it solved the issue.

The CSS I used:

```
.has-tip {
    background: rgba(208,208,208,0.1); /* Color of background. Also
           I am using RGBA because my background has a pattern thus 
           I lower the opacity of the background to show the pattern. */
    padding:3px;
}
```

Comment: Maybe you can look at a way to add this to core.

Comment: @Lynda Where is the .has-tip class defined? Did you add it to your scss or is it in a Foundation file?

Comment: @MattCamp - I am not using the SCSS just vanilla CSS and I added the style in my stylesheet so it overrides the Foundation style. You may want to ask on the [Foundation Forums](http://foundation.zurb.com/forum) for more specific help.

Comment: I've experienced this too and found that if the has-tip is too close to the tip element the flickering happens as the element is covered/not repeatedly. Moving has-tip away from the triggering element 5-10px further way seems to fix it.